# No agent found in pool which satisfies the specified java. self-hosted agent

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I have integrated SonarQube extension into TFS(2018) pipeline run Self hosted agent and on agent build machine have JAVA17. also build machine have the JAVA_HOME environment variable 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin', agent has been compatibility as well

[image]

Pipeline runs successfully many times before but suddenly fails with following error, but when I exclude SonarQube tasks from CI, its passes

```
 No agent found in pool 'name of pool' which satisfies the specified
 demands:
 
 msbuild 
 java
 Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.119.1
```

**The things which I did so far are:**

1_ Created new pipeline, install new agent

2_Changed the build machine

3_Added user compatibility under agent but no result.

Can any one please let me know what I am doing wrong. Really appriciated.

Comment: SonarQube requires Java. Is 'java' a capability of your agent? If not then on your build machine, did you install the agent and then install Java? Stop and start the agent service. On start, the agent will check for capabilities including Java. (What do you mean by "user compatibility under agent"?)

Comment: Yes you right. some one on my agent machine uninstalled JAVA thats why all my build start failing which have SQ tasks, after just install JAVA and restart the agent all working as expected
Thanks.